# When does the limit of $exp(-\alpha T)$ exist as $\alpha\to \infty$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, linear-transformations, matrix-exponential

I have the following situation: $T$ is a bounded linear operator on a Banach space $X$.

> Question: when does the limit
>   $$\lim_{\alpha\to \infty} \exp(-\alpha T)$$
>   exist as a bounded linear operator on $X$?

By "limit" I mean here either norm topology or strong operator topology, but any thoughts on  other topologies will be greatly appreciates as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partial answer: When the spectrum of $T$ is included in the real half-plane $H_+=\{ \mbox{Re } z >0 \}$ then the operator $e^{-\alpha T}$ goes to zero in norm. This may be seen from

$$ e^{-\alpha T} = \oint_C e^{-\alpha \lambda} (\lambda- T)^{-1} \frac{d\lambda}{2\pi i} $$
where the contour $C$ (enclosing the spectrum) may be chosen strictly inside $H_+$.

If, however, the spectrum touches the imaginary axis it becomes complicated. For example given the multiplication operator
$$ Tf(x) = x f(x),  \ x\in [0,1] $$ 
acting upon $L^1([0,1])$,  $e^{-\alpha T}$  goes to zero but not when acting upon $C([0,1])$ (no limit). In both cases the spectrum is $[0,1]$.
In the case of a matrix, eigenvalues should either have strictly positive real part or be zero without nilpotent part for the zero eigenvalue.

Comment: Thanks, that looks useful. Is there a good reference for this?

Comment: You may look for analytic or holomorphic semi-groups on the web or in books on funcitonal analysis. There is a small amount of information about this on wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_semigroup. It should be in Dunford& Schwartz but I don't have their books around. Otherwise e.g. Kato: Perturbation Theory for linear operators has a chapter on this in part IX, paragraph 1, section 6 (p 489 in my version from 1980). Often the concern is the case of unbounded operators where the situation is more delicate.

Comment: You are welcome! If you have a more concrete problem do not hesitate asking.